# (Where) Can I go to a "sleeper" cinema?

Tags: where-on-earth, entertainment, sleeping, cinema

I came upon an [article going around Facebook](http://www.boredpanda.com/beautiful-cinemas-around-the-world/#post0) which shows some unusual cinemas around the world. The first photo shows a number of movie-goers lying in beds watching a flick:

[image]

The article offers sparse details, at best, only claiming the location is "Olympia Music Hall, France" and a comment says "It was actually an event held by IKEA in France."

Are there any cinemas that do this regularly?

Comment: Don't know if something like that exists somewhere else but [Olympia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympia_(Paris)) is a well-known concert venue in Paris (in France an artist can “faire l'Olympia” and everybody knows what is meant) and is used for many other things. This one was definitely a one-time event, more info in French: [1](http://www.tout-paris.org/in-bed-with-ikea-a-lolympia-9991), [2](http://ubi-bene.fr/blog/2010/09/02/in-bed-with-ikea-a-lolympia/)

Comment: I have broadened the question a bit, to a) better match some of the existing answers, and b) provide an answer that's more useful to me. I'd enjoy visiting such a cinema, it needn't be the exact same one in the photo. Thanks to everyone who has answered so far!

Comment: I don't want to know, what happens with couples lying in beds with a romantic movie running ... ;-)

Comment: @johannes: The girl starts crying and the boy starts playing games on his phone.

Comment: the woman second row, second bed from bottom: is she in her panties?

Comment: @johannes The fact is that they seem to have put a lot more lighting than in ordinary cinemas, possibly out of concern for what might happen in the dark ;-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The depicted is not a regular event or an ongoing promotion.

In 2010, IKEA staged a promotion called *[In Bed with IKEA](http://vimeo.com/13356726)* at the [Olympia](http://www.olympiahall.com/) concert hall in Paris, in which the seats were replaced with a new bed and mattress line they were promoting. In late 2014, they staged a similar event called *[Cinema of Love](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/russian-cinema-teams-up-with-ikea-to-offer-movies-in-bed-9920083.html)* at [Kinostar De Lux](http://www.kinostardelux.ru/) in Khimki just outside Moscow.

The nearest I found to a real "bed" in a cinema is offered by Blitz Megaplex of Indonesia. They provide "[Velvet Class](http://www.blitzmegaplex.com/en/schedule_class_velvet.php)" amenities at several Jakarta locations featuring "lux sofabeds" with "fluffy pillows" and "warm and comfy blanket."

Beyond this, I found few offerings that could genuinely be called a *bed*. There are numerous theatres which offer sofas or day beds where a couple or small family can share a seat, from [The Landmark](http://www.landmarktheatres.com/los-angeles/the-landmark/info) in Los Angeles to the Portobello Road location of [Electric Cinema](http://www.electriccinema.co.uk/) in London to a number of Bangkok's "[VIP cinemas](http://travel.cnn.com/bangkok/play/bangkok-city-essentials/best-bangkok-vip-movie-theaters-270103)" like [SF Cinema City](http://www.sfcinemacity.com/index.php/th/cinema/location) and [Paragon Cineplex](http://www.majorcineplex.com/cinema/paragon-cineplex).

For a further possibility, there are [TGV Beanie](http://www.tgv.com.my/cinemas/halls/beanie.html) halls in Malaysia fitted with beanbag couches.

---

If you expand the criteria further to fully-reclining seats, the venues quickly become too many to list. Even very "Middle America" chains like AMC and Regal are installing [leather recliners](http://www.wsj.com/articles/now-at-the-movies-fully-reclining-seats-1404679140) to try to improve margins amidst declining moviegoing audiences; you can find them even in plain Jane suburbs like Beltsville, Maryland or Dublin, Ohio.

Comment: I have to say the beanbag cinema sounds like a really bad idea... beanbags are noisy!

Comment: Another one worth considering in the UK is [Everyman Cinemas](http://www.everymancinema.com/) where the atmosphere is very casual and seating is sofas and comfy furniture. I haven't been but I've heard nothing but good things.

Comment: @Anentropic: ...and bedsprings squeak. So? :-)))

Comment: They just upgraded the AMC here in Mountain View with the leather recliners, and I have to say it's very nice.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez Which one? There's no AMC in Mountain View proper.

Comment: @Kareen: the movie theater on Shoreline near Google. I think it's AMC. Maybe I'm mistaken. In any case they've remodeled and put in various spacious leather recliners.

Answer (score 14):

It's not quite the same but a similar style of venue recently opened in Budapest.

http://budaeg.com/?id=bed_movies&next_language

Their "beds" don't have the abundance of linen shown in the photo; it's more of a very, very deep lounge than a bed. But they still look pretty comfortable and you have the option of having food delivered to your bed during the movie.

Comment: Great idea! If the movie's good you've got a super-comfortable seat - and if it's not you can catch a nap!

Answer (score 9):

Your destination of choice is here in the UK. Based in an old London tube station is the one and only [Pillow Cinema](http://pillowcinema.com).

Answer (score 7):

The [Fairlee Motel & Drive-in Theater](http://www.fairleedrivein.com/) (in [Fairlee](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Fairlee+Motel/@43.922598,-72.125022,14z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xefc43dd6d4f80fb1), Vermont) is a motel with an attached drive-in cinema. The motel rooms have large windows facing the movie screen, and speakers for the audio.

Motel is open all year, but the drive-in theater is seasonal.

Answer (score 7):

In Australia, in Sydney, the closest to this would be [Govinda's Movie Room](http://www.govindas.com.au/) in Darlinghurst, which is walking distance from the city centre or Kings Cross.

Downstairs is an all you can eat Indian vegetarian buffet restaurant. I believe it was run by the Hari Krishnas but I'm not sure that it still is. It's good but not as cheap as other Hari Krishna restaurants I've been to.

Upstairs is the movie room, which has a few seats but mostly special mattresses you lie down on, which are not exactly like beds. The screen isn't so big so this is one cinema where I prefer the front row, especially with a full tummy.

You can buy a combined ticket for food and movie or just for the movie. The movies have just finished their run in regular cinemas and they rotate different movies each day and change the movies each week or month.

Answer (score 6):

There are lot of luxury cinemas around the word with cosy and comfy beds.

Few of them:

- The Blitz Megaplex chain in Jakarta, Indonesia offers sofa beds,
- Over in Thailand, the Paragon Cineplex in Bangkok offer big beds with blankets and fluffy pillows,
- In Malaysia, the Beanie chain of cinemas offer large beanbag seats instead of chairs,
- The Electric Cinema in London offers armchairs, sofas and giant red velvet.
- Pillow Cinema offer the cosiest "night in" night out (mostly on fatboy bean bags).

Source: [Beds in cinemas: 4 amazing places to watch a film](http://wedo.co.uk/community/beds-in-cinemas/)

For complete list, please look for luxury cinemas around your area.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to find the answer is if you search by image on google (https://images.google.com/). You will get the relevant answer.

It is the Parisian music hall Olympia that was filled with beds from Ikea to promote the Swedish company’s new line-up of mattresses.

Reference:
http://en.rocketnews24.com/2014/01/18/catch-a-movie-in-bed-at-the-theater-four-awesome-theaters-from-around-the-world-with-beds-for-seats/

Comment: So...why did a Swedish company go to France to promote a line of mattresses? Not enough mattress users in Sweden? Or are they more inhibited in France? :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis Presumably to promote them to French people, Sweden apparently has (well designs and orders somewhere else…) many more mattresses than inhabitants ;-)

Answer (score 4):

At [KingSpa](http://kingsaunanj.com/), at least in the Palisades Park, NJ US one, there are several rooms with sleeping/napping accommodations where they play movies. I think most of them are Korean, but they've been fun nonetheless when I've gone.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Your suggestion appears to be a spa that plays movies, however, not a cinema.

Comment: @choster sure, but it's certainly within the spirit of the question.

Comment: I think there is a big difference between a public theatre and a semi-private space where playing a film is an amenity rather than a primary service. If we expand the criteria to include any facility where you can watch a video, you can probably find dozens in any big city— or [even small ones](http://travel.cnn.com/explorations/life/vang-vieng-backpacker-heaven-or-tourist-hell-994621), or [even airplane cabins](http://www.virgin-atlantic.com/en/us/frequentflyer/fcnewsfeatures/doublebeds.jsp)— and this question would be unanswerable as too broad.

Comment: @choster I think that could be said about basically anything. Good day.

Comment: Hi Choster.  Welcome to the SE network. I see you're a new user and I hope you're enjoying it. When you are welcoming even newer users than yourself, please be moderate about extreme hairsplitting. After a few more years you'll have a better feel for this.  Cheers and I hope you stick with it   :)

Comment: @JoeBlow new user? He's been on the site for over 3 years!

Comment: Hi Mark - I was gently poking fun at Chos' supercilious comments which he made to Kate.

Answer (score 0):

These Cinemas in Mumbai/ Bombay, India provide Full Reclining loungers.

- Cinemax - Gold Class in Red Lounge
- PVR -  Gold Class

Both of these companies operate several Cinemas of this type in major cities across the country.